# Sendkey value disappear after pasting

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, sendkeys

Appreciate ay assistance in advance.

I am trying to use Sendkeys a dynamic value from a cell in Excel into my browser. this value is an employee AD ID. the AD ID is used in the Site to find the Staff. upon pasting the Employee AD ID in the browser the site tries to find the match but then the pasted Employee AD ID disappears.

potentially I want to be able to sendkeys the Employee AD ID and then select the given option if possible.

below is the element path. and the VBA script I am using.

```html
<div><div class="GDQHEYCCGGB"></div><div class="GDQHEYCCFGB"><input type="text" class="gwt-SuggestBox GDQHEYCCEGB" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" maxlength="20" id="gwt-uid-57" style="width: 10px; color: rgb(169, 169, 169);"></div></div>
```

I am able to click into the box by using below VBA code. and able to do sendkeys but upon pasting it disapears after the site automatically tries to search. but when I write the Employee AD ID manually it searches automatically and finds the Employee AD ID and then I manually select it

```
driver.FindElementByClass("GDQHEYCCDGB").Click
```

I tried FindElementbyXpath I can click into it but cant send any value.

Regards

Comment: Will the code send to a simple program like notepad or texteditor? Because form your description it may be the browser has the issue but you don't seem to consider that.

Comment: thank you for replying Solar Mike. yes it sends to notepad. the code sends the string to the browser but it disappears after the site's auto search takes effect. 
but when type the string manually it doesn't disappear. is there any other way to insert text maybe instead of sendkeys?

Comment: did you try with .sendkeys("String") if so try with the driver.findElement(Locator).sendKeys(Keys.A);
driver.findElement(Locator).sendKeys(Keys.B);
and do not do clean up because will get only one letter

Comment: thank you Gaj, what is (Keys.A)? i put below in and getting a Run-time error '404' Object required. driver.FindElementByClass("GDQHEYCCDGB").SendKeys (Keys.a)